# Button dropdown doesn't work on mobile when pull-right is set

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I noticed a strange behaviour in Bootstrap v. 3.3.4.
When I use button dropdowns, adding `pull-right` to `btn-group` to make it float to the right side seems to break the "click" when width is < 990px.
If I remove the `pull-right` class, everything works as expected.

This is my code:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right"><button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default" aria-expanded="false">Click me</button>
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" href="#" aria-expanded="true"><span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="my-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="my-item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It is a bug or my mistake?

Adding more context, I have to share also where the `button-group` is located:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="btn-group pull-right">...</div>
<div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <img class="logo-img" src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
    </div>
```

So actually, when window become smaller, the button was overlapped by the row beneath and by the image, effect not visible because of the transparency of the image itself.

Comment: It seems to be working fine ([see this JSFiddle with your HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/gf1t8sw7/2/)). Could there be any other style/script affecting the dropdown?

Comment: Hi @AlvaroMontoro thank your for your suggestion. It led me to the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the particular context described, I think it's not a bug but instead a bad implementation by myself.
A simple solution/workaround - although not elegant - to solve the issue is to add `z-index: 1000` to the `style` of the `button-group`. So you got:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right" style="z-index:1000">
...
</div>
```